# Azure tablestorage encrytped at rest

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Just read a release that says all azure storage is encrypted at rest, looking for a way to verify this for non-blobs or files . Specifically Table Storage.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-default-encryption-for-azure-blobs-files-table-and-queue-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. There is no way for a confirm this with a code check as the data is encrypted/decrypted transparently during write/read.  You can check to see if a particular blob is encrypted using get-blob - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob

x-ms-server-encrypted: true/false   Version 2015-12-11 or newer. The value of this header is set to true if the blob data and application metadata are completely encrypted using the specified algorithm. Otherwise, the value is set to false (when the blob is unencrypted, or if only parts of the blob/application metadata are encrypted).

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest

More detail:
If I am parsing your question correctly, Azure has rolled out encryption by default in all regions in Public Azure. This means that any new storage account (Classic or ARM) created will have Encryption at Rest enabled by default. Encrypting data in existing Storage accounts is ongoing (ETA to be completed by end of the year). Encryption for Tables and Queues at rest is also in the works.

You can check the blob and file headers per above to verify data is encrypted. Unfortunately there isn't a way currently to do such verifications for Tables and Queues.

Comment: Mark thanks for the response. My issue really is "enabling encryption by default using Microsoft Managed Keys for all data written to Azure services (Blob, File, Table and Queue storage" but all the other documentation lists client based keys for table storage encryption. I am just looking to validate the announcement either through code or the portal

Comment: See my More detail additions in the answer above.

Comment: Just so I understand completely, despite the words used in the announcement encryption at rest for Tables and Queues has not been deployed yet?

Comment: It is my understanding that encryption of Tables and Queues is in process.  However, there is no currently no way to verify that it has occurred or not on a particular table/queue.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question!